# IF statements on SQL queries

Tags: sql

I have the following query :

```
SELECT id, status from applications
```

Now, status can either be open, matched, completed. But when the query displays the results, I want open to be displayed as "In Progress", matched as "Approved" and completed as "Realized"

Is this in anyway possible from the SQL Select statement?

Comment: Which DBMS Do you use?

Comment: @Jens `CASE` is part of the T-SQL standard, all standards compliant DBMS' will support it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`CASE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx):

```
SELECT id,
       case status when 'open' then 'In Progress'
                   when 'matched' then 'Approved'
                   when 'completed' then 'Realized'
       end as status
from applications
```

Comment: Was about to post the exact same thing, you only beat me because I looked up the MSDN link, ill just put it in yours :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
   SELECT id, 
           Case status when 'open' then 'In Progress' 
                       WHEN 'matched' then 'approved' 
                       when 'completed' then 'Realized' 
            end 
     from applications
```